# Need to change image on hover for images in a grid

Tags: html, css

I have created a grid of images for my site. I created the grid in in my style sheet and then did the images with links in html. I would like to now make it where when I mouse over one of the images, it swaps to another image. I have 18 images, so that is 18 hovers.

thank you

this is the html I use, I use 18 versions of this

```
<div class="row22">
<div class="column22"><a href="https://www.allegrodanceboutique.com/ambassadors/isabella-shaker"><img style="width: 100%;" src="//static.shoplightspeed.com/shops/608846/files/13773857/isabella-shaker.jpg" /></a></div>
```

and the css

```
/* image containers */
.column22 {
  float: left;
  max-width: 20%;
  min-width: 300px;
  padding: 5px;
}

/* Clear floats after image containers */
.row22::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways of doing this. You can do it with javascript/jquery or you can do it with CSS too.

```css
.Standard{
display:inline-block;
}
.column22:hover .Standard{
display:none;
}

.ShowOnHover{
display:none;
}
.column22:hover .ShowOnHover{
display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="row22">
<div class="column22">
<a href="https://www.allegrodanceboutique.com/ambassadors/isabella-shaker">
<img class="Standard" style="width: 100%;" src="https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/660/cpsprodpb/37B5/production/_89716241_thinkstockphotos-523060154.jpg" />
<img class="ShowOnHover" style="width: 100%;" src="https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/images/ic/208x117/p0792vnb.jpg" />
</a></div>
```

Here I have both images in same `<a>`. En depending on hover or not, I hide/show the images. (Sorry for the bad naming of the classes, I did it to make it more clear for you)

You should know that if you do it this way, all images will be loaded on page. If they are very big, you may not want this, because it will take som time.

In that case you should use Javascript/jquery.

Then you can use this jquery code:

```
$('.img_class').hide(); // to hide image
$('.img_class').show(); // to show image
```

Comment: I will try this now and get back to you shortly. Thank you for the clear answer.

Comment: If your class column22 is not a class you are using everywhere you should give it two classes like this: `class="mycolumn column22"`. Now you can use `mycolumn:hover` instead.

Comment: So i entered it, and in the editor, both images show up separately, but when I go to the page and hover, the image does not change at all. However, the code remains and everything works fine...just no image change.

Comment: Then you havent named it correctly regarding to the CSS and Classes. Could you edit your question and add more code?

Comment: You are completely correct. I went back and reread what you wrote and reentered it into my stylesheet. It works perfectly. You are awesome. I just started doing this, so this was incredibly helpful. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Devloop80 I'd like to use your JQuery version. Would you mind showing how to implement it?